# Equivalent of simple groups in topology

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, finite-groups, simple-groups

I read about the classification theorem of finite simple groups, and I was wondering if there is a topological meaning to spaces that have a simple fundamental group?

In addition, is there something that we can learn about spaces with finite simple fundamental groups, by using the classification theorem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It means there are no nontrivial regular covering maps.